# WebRtcLocalhostIpHandling Policy makes webrtc peerConnection not working

Tags: javascript, html, webrtc, microsoft-edge, policy

There is a webrtc example from WebRTC org

https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/peerconnection/pc1/

It shows how to create Peer Connection between two peers. However, it is important to note that both peers are on the local computer. And this is also what we want, we need this peerConnection to gain AEC(audio echo cancel) benefit.

But in the network environment of our school,
We only use Edge(Chromium) to join webrtc webpage. And for safety reasons, we set WebRtcLocalhostIpHandling to default_public_interface_only, which makes the rtcpeerConnection broken, not working.

Let me explain:
WebRtcLocalhostIpHandling is a policy that influence the behavior of the Edge browser.
And the value default_public_interface_only means that Allows the use of a common interface over HTTP default routing.**This does not expose the local IP address**

Now is the question:
We need the rtcpeerConnection working and also need the policy setting, what should we do?
Is there some configuration for rtcPeerConnection api?

[image]

Comment: I agree with Philipp. According to [peer connections doc](https://webrtc.org/getting-started/peer-connections), STUN or a TURN server will provide ICE candidates to each client which is then transferred to the remote peer. It translates the local IP address to the public IP address to send out. You can also find more information about STUN server and TURN server in [this article](https://blog.addpipe.com/troubleshooting-webrtc-connection-issues/) and [this article](https://rollout.io/blog/webrtc-issues-and-how-to-debug-them/).

Comment: You can try to set this policy: [WebRtcLocalIpsAllowedUrls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/microsoft-edge-policies#webrtclocalipsallowedurls). It can specify a list of origins (URLs) or hostname patterns for which local IP address should be exposed by WebRTC. You can set your site in this policy.

Answer (score 2):

The samples do not use a STUN server so they are going to break in that particular case. This should not be an issue when you pass a working STUN (or TURN) server to the RTCPeerConnection constructor.

Comment: Thanks, I  tried STUN server, but it seems not working.I will later upload an Github example URL to show the demo.

Comment: And this is demo url : https://ajlovechina.github.io/webrtc-rtcpeerconnection-default_public_interface_only/

I tried STUN server : stun:stun.l.google.com:19302
Yes, both peer connection can have successful icecandidate event, and retrieve public IP from stun server.But P2P connection not working on the same web page.

Comment: And it's worth explaining that the Edge(Chromium) browser environment I'm running in has policy set.(WebRtcLocalhostIpHandling  = default_public_interface_only) .
For Edge(Chromium) that don't have this policy set, the demo runs normally.